# AttributeError: 'CameraOpenCV' object has no attribute 'fps' when trying to run Camera Example on Kivy

Tags: python, opencv, kivy

I want to develop an App which uses the camera of the phone. I am setting up the environment and tried to run the camera example from [here](https://kivy.org/docs/examples/gen__camera__main__py.html). I get this error log:

```
user@ubuntulinux:~/Documents/Android/TestApp$ python3 main.py 
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/user/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-04-24_1.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.0 Mesa 17.2.8'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Open Source Technology Center'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) '>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.30'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Camera      ] Provider: opencv
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 605, in _apply_rule
     setattr(widget_set, key, value)
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 33, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__ (kivy/weakproxy.c:1236)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 478, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__ (kivy/properties.c:5171)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 815, in kivy.properties.ListProperty.set (kivy/properties.c:11368)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 516, in kivy.properties.Property.set (kivy/properties.c:5933)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 571, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch (kivy/properties.c:6614)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1225, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:13524)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1131, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy/_event.c:12723)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/uix/camera.py", line 103, in _on_index
     resolution=self.resolution, stopped=True)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/camera/camera_opencv.py", line 67, in __init__
     super(CameraOpenCV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/camera/__init__.py", line 70, in __init__
     self.init_camera()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/camera/camera_opencv.py", line 121, in init_camera
     if self.fps <= 0:
 AttributeError: 'CameraOpenCV' object has no attribute 'fps'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 59, in <module>
     TestCamera().run()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 802, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "main.py", line 56, in build
     return CameraClick()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/uix/boxlayout.py", line 131, in __init__
     super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 345, in __init__
     Builder.apply(self, ignored_consts=self._kwargs_applied_init)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 451, in apply
     self._apply_rule(widget, rule, rule, ignored_consts=ignored_consts)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 612, in _apply_rule
     e), cause=tb)
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 6:
 ...
       4:    Camera:
       5:        id: camera
 >>    6:        resolution: (640, 480)
       7:        play: False
       8:    ToggleButton:
 ...
 AttributeError: 'CameraOpenCV' object has no attribute 'fps'
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 605, in _apply_rule
     setattr(widget_set, key, value)
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 33, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__ (kivy/weakproxy.c:1236)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 478, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__ (kivy/properties.c:5171)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 815, in kivy.properties.ListProperty.set (kivy/properties.c:11368)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 516, in kivy.properties.Property.set (kivy/properties.c:5933)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 571, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch (kivy/properties.c:6614)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1225, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:13524)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1131, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy/_event.c:12723)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/uix/camera.py", line 103, in _on_index
     resolution=self.resolution, stopped=True)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/camera/camera_opencv.py", line 67, in __init__
     super(CameraOpenCV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/camera/__init__.py", line 70, in __init__
     self.init_camera()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/camera/camera_opencv.py", line 121, in init_camera
     if self.fps <= 0:
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5.2. I am not using a virtual machine.

The error seems to indicate some OpenCV issue so here is my OpenCV Version:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.0.0-pre'
>>>
```

I installed OpenCV and Kivy globally. I followed the instruction for OpenCV installation from [here](http://cyaninfinite.com/tutorials/installing-opencv-in-ubuntu-for-python-3/) and I installed Kivy with [this](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html). Did I do something wrong during the installation or why do I get this error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like those instructions for OpenCV tell you to fetch the development branch (i.e. not necessarily stable -- there's work in progress on OpenCV 4.0, which may involve breaking changes to the API). Unless you want to work on the OpenCV code itself, that's probably not a very good idea. I'd suggest to check out a tag (say 3.4.1) and rebuild, so that you're using a tested and officially supported version.

Comment: You are right! It works now!